# GPO to enable Windows Hello Face Recog. and Fingerprint but no PIN

Tags: windows, group-policy, authentication, fingerprint, face-recognition

How can I configure GPO to enable Windows Hello Face recog. and fingerprint but without PIN?

Comment: See if these resources help: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-cert-trust-policy-settings and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/user-profiles-and-logon/facial-recognition-logon-not-work-group-policy-setting

Answer (score 0):

It seems we need to Turn on convenience PIN sign-in for the Fingerprint to work.
Best Regards,